# cannot resolve constructor for FirebaseListAdapter (Android)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I'm trying to follow along with the following tutorial:

[Retrieving data in realtime with Firebase Events - Firecasts #2](https://youtu.be/2FRBDXBs30Y)

Around the 14:00 minute mark, you will see the following code introduced:

```
    FirebaseListAdapter<String> adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<String>(this,
            String.class, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, messagesRef) {

        protected void populateView(View v, String model, int position) {
            TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            textView.setText(model);
        }
    };
```

However my Android Studio underlines the constructor parameters in red and when I hover my mouse over the underlined area, a message pops up saying "cannot resolve constructor '[elaborate abstract description of my constructor w/ params]'.  I wish I could cut and paste what it says exactly, but I can't find any way of doing that.

Anyhow... In my infinite knowledge, I inspected the underlying (imported) class, FirebaseListAdapter.java (in case there had been some kind of changes to the constructor requirements since the video was made), and I can see no reason why my constructor (which isn't really "my" constructor -- it's the one from the video) doesn't work.

Thanks for any help!

PS - I know someone is going to ask for more code so here is the entire MainActivity:

```
package com.testing123.firecast2;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.firebase.client.ChildEventListener;
import com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot;
import com.firebase.client.Firebase;
import com.firebase.client.FirebaseError;
import com.firebase.client.ValueEventListener;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseListAdapter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

static final String TAG = "FireBase2";

// Firebase

Firebase mRootRef;
Firebase messagesRef;

// ArrayList<String> mMessages = new ArrayList<>();

// UI

TextView mTextView;
ListView mListView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mRootRef = new Firebase ("https://firecast002.firebaseio.com/");

    mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

}


@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    messagesRef = mRootRef.child("messages");

    // adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mMessages);
    FirebaseListAdapter<String> adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<String>(this,
            String.class, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, messagesRef) {

        protected void populateView(View v, String model, int position) {
            TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            textView.setText(model);
        }
    };



    mListView.setAdapter(adapter);

    /* messagesRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            // String message = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);

            // mTextView.setText(message);

            // that was how its done for single key value pair... but now we're doing multiple children under "message"

            Map<String,String> map = dataSnapshot.getValue(Map.class);
            String message1 = map.get("message1");
            String message2 = map.get("message2");

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
        }
    });  */

    // that was how its done for valuevent listener... now we treat the children of "message" key as list items
    // and use a childeventlistener instead

    /* messagesRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        // gets fired for every INITIAL child member.
        // only gets sent a string, not a downstream dataset
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            String message = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            Log.i(TAG, "child added: " + message + " ... and by the way, String 's' is" + s);
            mMessages.add(message);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            String message = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            Log.i(TAG, "child changed: " + message + " ... and by the way, String 's' is" + s);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            String message = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            Log.i(TAG, "child removed: " + message);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
        }
    });
    */
    // that was the hard way, now we use FirebaseUI





}
}
```

Comment: Everything seems legit. I visited [this link](https://firebaseui.com/docs/android/com/firebase/ui/FirebaseListAdapter.html) to see the available constructors for it, and it seems like you got it. Did you try googling your error to see if somebody had it?

Comment: have you added firebase ui in your dependcies gradle file                compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0:3.1'

Comment: could you share what errors you are getting

Comment: I suggest you go to google.firebase.com and install that version of firebase instead of using the old deprecated version you have now from firebase.com. Its possible that firebaseUI updated their library to use the new firebase in which case it would make sense that its not working for you.

Comment: It seems like you're trying to mix the Firebase 2.x SDK and the FirebaseUI library for 3.x. If you're using the Firebase 2.x SDK, use FirebaseUI 0.3. Alternatively you'll need to update to using the Firebase 3.x SDK, in which can you can use FirebaseUI 0.4 and up.

Comment: Frank that was the problem... THANKYOU... I dont know how you knew that... but I changed the line in gradle to: compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.3.1' and now it works.

Comment: Oh... I guess it's because you are an "engineer for Firebase at Google." YAY!  Well sweet!  Just so you know... even on the latest version of Android Studio, when you add firebase via the pull down menus (as shown in the tutorial I referenced originally), Android Studio still adds the old version: compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'

Answer (score 0):

Update your project to add the latest version of firebase UI

'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.4.3'

Answer (score -1):

I had the same error. After many tries I think I found a solution.

1. First, add this library to your dependencies:

   `implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.6.2'`
2. Next, copy and paste this import to your activity import:

   `import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseListAdapter;`